# How do I create a search filter text box in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assuming I have a `div` structure with a textbox:

```
<input id="filter" type="text" name="fname" /><br />
<input type="text">
<div id="listofstuff">
    <div class="anitem">
        <span class="item name">Dog</span>
        <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="anitem">
        <span class="item name">Doodle Bird</span>
        <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="anitem">
       <span class="item name">Cat</span>
       <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make it so that initially.. say it shows 3 `anitems`, I want to make it so that if the user has any character typed into the search box, it would only show the divs that match with the entry the user is typing.

Ex. So if the user types "D", it would hide all other divs without "D" in the "item name". 
If the user types another letter "og", then the only div that would be shown is the div with" item name" of "Dog"
If the user hits the delete key to remove the "g", then the two divs "Dog" and "Doodle Bird" would be show.
If the user deletes everything they typed in the text box, then all the anitems would show up.

How do I accomplish this if possible? I think I may have to use .live() but I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have to handle the `keyup` event (which is clicked *after* key is released) then use `.filter()` to find matching items, showing their parents.

```
$("#filter").bind("keyup", function() {
    var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var items = $(".item_name");

    //first, hide all:
    items.parent().hide();

    //show only those matching user input:
    items.filter(function () {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) == 0;
    }).parent().show();
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/qcQ7X/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You want to handle the keyup event and i think you can do this:

```
$('div').each(function() {
   $(this).toggle($(this).children('span.itemname').text() == yourVar);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter as the user types, you should attach an event handler to the textbox's `keypress`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)</sup>* event. Everytime the user presses a key, you can `filter`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)</sup>* the contents of `#listofstuff` and either `show`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://api.jquery.com/show/)</sup>* or `hide`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)</sup>* it.